# Prove That $m\geq\frac{5}{6}(n-5)$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Question:

> A city has $n$ bus lines. Every bus stop is on at most $3$ bus lines and every bus line has at least $2$ bus stops. Besides, for any $2$ lines $l_1$ and $l_2$, there exists a line $l_3$ such that $l_1$ and $l_3$ share a bus stop, and $l_3$ and $l_2$ share a bus stop. Let $m$ be the total number of bus stops. Prove that $m\geq\frac{5}{6}(n-5)$.

This problem is from a book on Math Olympiads that I am currently studying. No solutions were provided, but a hint was given: "Consider lines that only has $2$ bus stops". From this I was able to develop some ideas. They are as follows.

If every bus line has at least $3$ bus stops, consider pairs $(A, l)$ where $A$ is a bus stop on line $l$. Let $k$ be the number of such pairs. Since every bus stop is on at most $3$ bus lines, we know that $3m\geq k$. Since we assumed that every line has at least $3$ bus stops, we know that $k\geq3n$. Hence, $3m\geq k\geq3n\implies m\geq n\geq\frac{5}{6}(n-5)$.

Hence, suppose that there exists a line $l$ with only $2$ bus stops. Let these $2$ bus stops be called $A$ and $B$. Call all lines that pass through $A$ and/or $B$ "type-1 lines". Since each bus stop is on at most $3$ bus lines, there are at most $5$ "type-1 lines". Call all other lines "type-2 lines". From the third condition, every "type-2 line" must share a stop with a "type-1 line".

I stopped here. I could not figure out anything from this last statement. Any help on this question will be appreciated!

Comment: I tried for a while and then gave up.  I wonder if graph theory, whatever that is, would be relevant.  My speculation is that trying to solve the problem without looking for relevant graph theory theorems to apply may be similar to trying to re-invent the wheel.  I could easily be mistaken.

Comment: I am looking for an elementary solution without graph theory. This question was under the chapter "bijection principle", and the entire book has no graph theory, so I think it is doable. I am still thinking about it and will post the solution if I find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a shaky answer. I'm sure that claim 2 is correct, but I do not think my counting for it is.

Claim: We can always fit $n$ lines onto $n-1$ stops if $ n \geq 3$.

Proof: Name our lines $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4, \ldots$, and choose $l_2,l_3, l_4, \ldots$ to be of length 2. Then, we can wrap $l_1$ around every other stop such that no stop has more than three lines on it and for any two lines $l_i, l_j$, they both share a stop with $l_1$. Also, for $l_1$ and $l_i$, they would both share a stop with some line who neighbors $l_i$. For a picture, draw a ($n$-$1$)-gon, name every side of it $l_2,l_3, \ldots$, and then draw a line skipping every vertex in a circle, starting from the stop, name that line $l_1$ (If I knew how to make images on here I would). This is our $n-1$ configuration. This is not super useful in the proof, but rather helps with our understanding of how this works.

Claim 2: We can never fit $n$ lines onto less than $n-5$ stops.

First, if $n \leq 6$, we don't have 2 stops so we obviously cant do it.

Now, let $n \geq 7$. If we start with our $n-1$ stop configuration and remove 4 stops, then we need to keep the rest of stops so there should be an extra $8$ stops at full capacity (possibly I'm not $100%$ sure on this). Then, we still need to connect all minimum of $4$ lines to every other one. However, our main connecting line $l_1$ cannot reach these lines, so all $4$ of them would need their own. But, we chose $1$ line to do it alone because that single line minimized the total number of stops we required. However, seeing that we needed $\frac{n}{2}$ stops for 1 line to do it, we would need an extra $n$ capacity, which we do not have (we have $3n - 15$ total, and we use $2n$ for every line to be of length 2. I think this is the least strong part of the proof, as I'm not sure how to put it into words.

Claim 4: If $m \geq n - 5$, $m \geq \frac{5}{6}(n - 5)$.

Proof: Assume the minimum value of m, i.e. $m = n - 5$. Then $m = n-5 \geq \frac{5}{6}(n-5)$, and hence our equality holds.

I hope this helps at least by giving ideas on how you would solve this. Also, as the chapter is titled "The Bijection Principle", you can see that you should be counting the minimum number of stops needed for $n$ lines.

Comment: Perhaps a more eloquent argument is: If we have 1 line being the connector, we can touch every line with $\frac{n}{2}$ stops. If we have $2$ lines connecting all of them, we would need at least $n$ stops (out of a total of $n$). When we have $n-6$ stops and $n$ lines, we would be forced to need $2$ lines to be connectors at least. This is impossible, as we are beyond our capiacity at $3n - 18$. The point of claim 1 is too illustrate how the concept works, and why we can minimize it this way.

Comment: I still feel that this proof is not very rigorous. I will accept this for now, but I posted my own solution. I would appreciate it if you could check it out and verify it. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing here. You need to prove this for every possible configuration, not just the specially selected ones that you have chosen (EG The n-1 gon example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found. Feel free to post alternative solutions or point out areas of improvements in mine. This proof uses double counting so I am still open to any solutions that uses bijection principle.

This proof continues from my works in the question. Let all bus stops on a type-1 line be called type-1 stops and all other bus stops be called type-2 stops. Note that this means that if a bus stop is on both a type-1 line and a type-2 line, the bus stop is still called a type-1 stop. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of type-1 and type-2 lines. Let $x$ and $y$ be the number of type-1 and type-2 stops. Then, $x+y=m$.

Consider pairs $(A, l)$ where $A$ is a bus stop on line $l$, and $l$ is a type-2 line (why does $(A, l)$ look so ugly??). Let there be $k$ such pairs.

Since $X\leq5$ (check the question for the explanation), we get $Y\geq n-5$. Hence, since every line has at least $2$ bus stops, we have $2(n-5)\leq2Y\leq k$. Since every type-1 stop is on at most $2$ type-2 lines and every type-2 stop is on at most $3$ type-2 lines, we also have $k\leq2x+3y=2m+y$.

Writing everything together, we have $2(n-5)\leq k\leq 2m+y\implies m\geq(n-5)\geq\frac{5}{6}(n-5)$.

I do not see any errors but I am not entirely confident either. It seems weird that there is a random $\frac{5}{6}$ that is not needed. If anyone could provide a plausible explanation, I would appreciate it.